# replacement for plotshape when the input is arrays not series? can I use plotshape for elements of an array?

Tags: pine-script

I am wondering if there is any replacement for `plotshape`.

In my code I have something like this

```
plotshape(condition,   style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.blue,50),  offset = -1 , size=size.auto)
```

at the time the `condition` was computed on fly and it was working great with `plotshape`, but now I have an array, I go back and forth on the array and create a new conditions, now I wanna plot something like `shape.triangledown` on the top or bellow some of the bars.
I tried to use `label.new`, but I dont like it since it is kinda weird looking and is not as clean as `plotshape`,

does anyone have any suggestion for me?
I cannot use `plotshape` anymore since my condition are saved in an array and apparently I cannot use the `plotshape` in a for loop for every element of the my array. (or if I can then I dont know how, so please tell me how)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is using `label`s.

If you don't like the looks of it, instead of using `style=label.style_label_up`, you can actually use symbols like `▲` as text. That will have a more similar look as `plotshape`.

```
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, "▲", yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 100), textcolor=color.white)
    label.new(bar_index -1, high, "", yloc=yloc.belowbar, style=label.style_label_up, color=color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Just out of curiosity, where did you get the "▲"? I am trying to find the opposite of it as well?

Comment: I got it from [here](https://fsymbols.com/signs/triangle/) but I just Googled "triangle emoji". There are many other websites as well.